# Black Screen after login

Tags: 14.04, login, gdm

Hello guys i just installed ubuntu 14.04 and i had a hard time full of problems anyways as i thought problems had finished i restarted after update of software and tried to login but i had a black  screen for like half a second then i was back at the login screen *note * when i was running and in ubuntu i couldnt view the bar on the side or any of the programmes on desktop i managed though to enter settings fine (i have gdm installed as said in other forums)

**System specs**

**CPU** AMD a6 3670k
**GPU** ON board graphics
**MOBO** GA-A55M-S2V
**RAM** 1 gb gddr3 RAM
**HDD** 160 gb hdd

Comment: Did you install the normal version of Ubuntu (Unity)?